# Stripe Subscription object from Invoice object is null

Tags: java, json, stripe-payments

I'm parsing event webhooks, and for the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event I need to get the `Invoice` object, the `Subscription` object, and the `Plan` object:

```java
            if (event.getType().equals("invoice.payment_succeeded")) {
                Invoice invoice = (Invoice) event.getData().getObject();
                Subscription subscription = invoice.getSubscriptionObject();
                Plan plan = subscription.getPlan();
```

The problem is that the `Subscription` object it's getting is null, so I can't get the plan, but in the webhook json, the invoice is clearly not null:

```
<com.stripe.model.Invoice@1862723626 id=in_1EAqJIJIKy5oOMbPbbnFDfhe> JSON: {
  "id": "in_1EAqJIJIKy5oOMbPbbnFDfhe",
  "object": "invoice",
  "amount_due": 500,
  "amount_paid": 500,
  "amount_remaining": 0,
  "application_fee": null,
  "attempt_count": 1,
  "attempted": true,
  "auto_advance": false,
  "billing": "charge_automatically",
  "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
  "charge": "ch_1EAqJIJIKy5oOMbPzJWZRmkB",
  "created": 1551842448,
  "currency": "usd",
  "custom_fields": null,
  "customer": "cus_EdkAtTWX48vPlL",
  "date": 1551842448,
  "default_source": null,
  "deleted": null,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "due_date": null,
  "ending_balance": 0,
  "finalized_at": 1551842448,
  "footer": null,
  "hosted_invoice_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_Xk5QCVu0wZGe8yDKRjNku8do3v",
  "invoice_pdf": "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_Xk5QCVu0wZGe8yDKRjNku8do3v/pdf",
  "lines": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "sli_b7542154e3401d",
        "object": "line_item",
        "amount": 500,
        "currency": "usd",
        "description": "1 ? Service (at $5.00 / month)",
        "discountable": true,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {},
        "period": {
          "end": 1554520848,
          "start": 1551842448
        },
        "plan": {
          "id": "plan_EYQ3ShMp3aS5RZ",
          "object": "plan",
          "active": true,
          "amount": 500,
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1550523572,
          "currency": "usd",
          "interval": "month",
          "interval_count": 1,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": "535281012935229482:540347090178670611",
          "product": "prod_EYQ2LpVmAUc2Kh",
          "tiers": null,
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_usage": null,
          "usage_type": "licensed",
          "deleted": null,
          "name": null,
          "statement_description": null,
          "statement_descriptor": null,
          "trial_period_days": null
        },
        "proration": false,
        "quantity": 1,
        "subscription": "sub_Ee8abQjuYiFJXx",
        "subscription_item": "si_Ee8aKEipOAG8hQ",
        "type": "subscription"
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1EAqJIJIKy5oOMbPbbnFDfhe/lines",
    "count": null,
    "request_options": null,
    "request_params": null
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What does your stack trace look like?

Comment: It looks like you only copied and pasted a piece of the `Event` object. An `Invoice` object always contains the attribute `subscription`, which is not present in the code you posted. Can you show us the whole object please?

Comment: It does have the subscription attribute close to the bottom of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the value of the `subscription` attribute can be null, for example in the case of [one-off invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/one-off).

The whole `Subscription` object is not included in the `Invoice` object by default, only its identifier is. The `Invoice` object contained in the `Event` object follows the same rule. So you will need to retrieve the `Subscription` with its identifier as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve?lang=java)

```java
if (event.getType().equals("invoice.payment_succeeded")) {
    Invoice invoice = (Invoice) event.getData().getObject();
    Subscription subscription = Subscription.retrieve(invoice.getSubscription());
}
```

The `plan` attribute will only be set if the subscription contains a single plan.

Note that you can "expand" Stripe objects when retrieving them. See the section [Expanding Objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=java) of the Stripe API Reference.

Answer (score 1):

It states in the docs the data will only contain the [relevant object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data-object) for your webhook.

In an invoice's case, it's the invoice object only. Luckily that contains the `subscription` ID for you:

```
"subscription": "sub_Ee8abQjuYiFJXx",
```

You can use this ID to [retrieve the data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve?lang=java) as

```
Subscription subscription = Subscription.retrieve("sub_Ee8abQjuYiFJXx");
```